# Where are Logical addresses located?

Tags: operating-system

I know that user program generates logical addresses.Suppose there is a small code snippet in C .When address is printed,the addresses are virtual addresses.My question is where are those addresses fetched from?where exactly do the allocated values and variables stay?At main memory or secondary memory?If main memory then why there is physical address?

Comment: You should read the WP article on virtual memory.

Answer (score 0):

User mode programs only see logical addresses. Only the operating system (kernel mode) sees physical memory.

> My question is where are those addresses fetched from?

Those are the logical addresses assigned by the program loader ad linker.

> where exactly do the allocated values and variables stay?At main memory or secondary memory?

In a virtual memory system, it may be in main memory or secondary storage.

> If main memory then why there is physical address?

It is a logical address that is mapped to a physical address using page tables.

Comment: Suppose the logical address is #23xyz (a random address).Where in storage does this address point to?if user program generates logical addresses , in which memory are the values for corresponding variables stored?

Comment: @AjaySadanand I recommend you start reading about page tables.

Comment: The operating system defines a page table for each process that the CPU uses to map logical pages to physical page frames. The translation takes place transparently to the process.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am kind of new to the computer architecture and Operating System,
   but I will try to answer as much as I can.  As far as I have
   understood about the logical address (Which I still have trouble
   understanding, about where it is fetched from or where it is stored.
   I mean these addresses (numbers) gotta be stored somewhere,
   otherwise CPU can't generate it by itself, right?), these addresses
   are assigned by CPU or a processor and depends on the CPU
   architecture. Each process is assigned a virtual/logical
   address. And this logical address is translated to physical address
   by Memory Management Unit of CPU (MMU).
2. Where exactly do the allocated values and variables stay? As user3344003 said, it may be in main memory or secondary storage.
3. If main memory then why there is physical address? The reason lies
   in the concept of Virtual Memory. Each process has its own virtual
   address and a page table. Process's logical address are mapped
   through this page table to the Physical memory (RAM). Whatever that
   logical address is, it gets mapped to Physical address. If the
   Physical memory gets full, then OS evicts some of    the less used
   or unused process to Secondary storage and puts the needed process
   in the RAM. That way multiple process can run at the same time.
   Every process assumes that they have all the space in RAM just for
   themselves. If not for virtual memory, then physical memory would be
   full and process might crash and may shut down the OS as well.

*Hope it helps. I am still learning, if my understanding about Logical address and virtual memory is wrong then Please comment.*